# Get Wordpress menu position of current page

Tags: php, wordpress, menuitem

I have a Wordpress menu that is working fine. What I want to archieve now, is to display on each page the position in that menu like this:
Home > Current > News
if I am on the News page and this
Personal > Group > Our Team
if I am on the Our Team page...

It is not hard to read out the current title of the page of course, but this is only the last item. How can I get the parent menu items?

Thanks a lot!
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

This is called a 'Breacrumb' and is a good feature to have as it makes the site easier to navigate and helps with your SEO. Whenever I want a breadcrumb I use the breadcrumb feature of the [SEO plugin by Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/).

This plugin allows you to configure your breadcrumb and gives you a line of code or shortcode to put into your theme or content.

Regards

Dan